# How can I calculate the number of matrix additions, multiplications and divisions in AlexNet?

Tags: neural-networks, time-complexity, alexnet

I'm a first-year student in machine learning and I really recently started to immerse myself.

I need to **calculate number of**:

- matrix additions
- matrix multiplications
- matrix divisions

which are processed in the well known convolutional neural network - [AlexNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlexNet).

I found some [materials](http://vision.stanford.edu/teaching/cs231b_spring1415/slides/alexnet_tugce_kyunghee.pdf) about it, but I'm really confused about where to start.

So, the overall structure might look like:

[image: AlexNet structure overview]

But, how can I calculate operations for each type distinctly?